# Adicionar imagem no DataTables conforme estado

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Ando aqui as voltas com o DataTables e pretendia adicionar numa `img` cosoante o tipo de estado. Se o valor for `0` coloca uma imagem e ser for `1` coloca outra imagem na *row*.

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Poderia postar o código onde inicializa o DataTables, por favor. Existem várias formas de se fazer isso, então talvez ajude na resposta. Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Dado que você tem um conjunto de dados no atributo `data` na inicialização das colunas do seu DataTable, você pode usar o atributo [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) para modificar a forma como o plugin vai renderizar cada coluna.

Nesse atributo, você pode especificar uma função onde pode definir exatamente qual valor será mapeado para qual valor.

Considere o exemplo (extraído da documentação):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 4,
    "data": "description",
    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return type === 'display' && data.length > 40 ?
        '<span title="'+data+'">'+data.substr( 0, 38 )+'...</span>' :
        data;
    }
  } ]
} );
```

Note que nesse exemplo há apenas uma coluna, mas o mesmo se aplica a um *array* de colunas.

A função para transformar os números `0` e `1` em uma imagem poderia ser algo como:

```
function (data, type, full, meta) {
    var img = data == 0 ? 'desativado.jpg' : 'ativado.jpg';
    return type === 'display' ? '<img src="'+img+'">' : data;
}
```

Note ainda a comparação `type === 'display'`. Isso faz com que a imagem seja retornada para exibição, mas o dado original seja usado para ordenação, filtro, etc. Para alterar o valor usado numa busca, por exemplo, você pode comparar o valor de `type === 'filter'`.

Por fim, existe [uma resposta relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941917/1683070) que talvez seja útil para consulta. Lá você encontra o seguinte exemplo:

```
personTable = $("#person-table").DataTable({
    order: [1, "desc"],
    "autoWidth": false,
    ajax: {
        url: uri,
        dataSrc: "",
    },
    "columns": [
    { "data": "FirstName", "title": "Name" },
    { "data": "Address", "title": "Address" },
    { "data": "IsActive", "title": "Active" }
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return row.FirstName + " " + row.LastName;
            },
            "targets": 1
        },
        {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                return (data === true) ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
            },
            "targets": 2
        }
    ]
});
```

É quase a mesma coisa, só que aqui usando os ícones do Bootstrap ao invés de tags `<img>`.

Comment: sim a partida deve ser isso vou testar

Answer (score 0):

Sim funcionou em pleno

```
"columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": 6,
                "data": "RESOLVIDO",
                "render": function (data, type) {
                var img = data == 0 ? 'img/close.jpg' : 'img/ok.jpg';
                return type === 'display' ? '<img src="'+img+'">' : data;
            }
```

Comment: Isso é a resposta para a sua pergunta ou é um complemento da resposta do utluiz?

Comment: é uma solução a proposta